# UWP Sideloading App updates automatically

Tags: uwp, msbuild, visual-studio-app-center

I have a UWP app that is built with MSBuild.
Recently the app has been updating itself.

I don't have an entry for **UpdateSettings** in the .Appinstaller and neither **/p:AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency**
nor  **/p:AppInstallerUpdateFrequency** is set in MSBuild.

Where are the automatic updates coming from and where can I stop them.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the app publish to the store ?

Comment: no the app is provided via Microsoft App center.